# Error composer 1.8.4 on magento 2.3.0 CE

Tags: composer, magento2.3

I got this warning :

```
Warning: Unsupported declare 'strict_types' in /home/SITE_NAME/public_html/vendor/magento/inventory-composer-installer/src/Plugin.php on line 6
```

And this error :

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ';' or '{' in /home/SITE_NAME/public_html/vendor/magento/inventory-composer-installer/src/Plugin.php on line 55
```

Every time that I run a composer commande line like :

```
composer -V
```

I have :
CentOS Linux release 7.5.1804 (Core); PHP 7.2 (via cPanel) ; Latest magento 2.3.0 CE

Someone can help?

Comment: Post this in answer, so that it will helpful  for others

Answer (score 1):

Problem resolved, problem was at PHP version, HTTP requests use PHP7.2 but Commande line use the default PHP and it was PHP5.6!